# How to create an off switch for a socket that doesn't have one using a light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, socket

Two pronged European style sockets don't have an on off switch for sockets. I would like to have one, to stop the current from reaching the devices connected directly to the socket. I can place a light switch next to every socket, but what wiring will allow me to connect them?

Kind of like this photo but the switch is for the socket not any lights:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how flexible Europe is as far as using country X's stuff in country Y.  Can you fit common-as-dirt UK receptacles on your house, and get UK-to-your-system adapters?  All UK receptacles do indeed have switches right on the receptacle.

Comment: Is there no way to do it manually? It would be pointless getting uk receptical since you can't plug into it here.

Comment: Sure.  If your country has something like the NEMA-5 switch-receptacle combo in your picture, those can be easily wired to switch the adjacent outlet.  Obviously you would want the style with your socket.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building from scratch, go ahead and put a wall switch next to the outlet. Then wire the wall switch so it is between the mains and the outlet.

If you just want to retrofit one outlet or so, you could add something like [this](http://www.popp.eu/products/actuators/wall-plug-switch/) to an existing socket:

[image: Wall plug switch]

This model has a local button, and also supports Z-wave for wireless switching.

[Here's another version](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B017X72IES/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&psc=1) which supports Alexa/Google Home.

Comment: If I were to put a light switch in between the connection to receptical, wouldn't that diminish the power since light switches are labeled something like 10A?  I can do that and it may switch it off but concerned about that. I didn't know these existed I will check them out.

Comment: European outlets are usually 16amps; I would be very surprised if you cannot find a 16amp switch at a local hardware store